# Call function in loop line and store return value to variable to then be used in the loop?

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

I want to do something like the following:

```
while myFunc() as myVar:
    print myVar
```

Basically, just call a function in the loop line that will return a value and continue the loop depending on that value, but I would also like to be able to use that value within the loop and I would rather not have to call the function a 2nd time.

What I would like to avoid:

```
while myFunc():
    myVar = myFunc()
    print myVar
```

Comment: Nope, sorry. You'll have to find another language, Python doesn't do assignments in expressions (too easy to create bugs).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can accomplish this using the two-argument version of the [`iter()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#iter) built-in function:

```
for myVar in iter(myFunc, sentinel):
    print myVar
```

This is equivalent to the following:

```
while True:
    myVar = myFunc()
    if myVar == sentinel:
        break
    print myVar
```

From the docs for `iter()`:

> If the second argument, *sentinel*, is given, then *o* must be a callable
>   object. The iterator created in this case will call *o* with no
>   arguments for each call to its `next()` method; if the value returned is
>   equal to sentinel, `StopIteration` will be raised, otherwise the value
>   will be returned.

Answer (score 0):

Use a generator that returns that value.

```
for myVal in myFunc():
 print myVal
```

This is in combination of the yield statement.

Comment: Why not a gen-exp? `for myVal in (myFunc() for _ in itertools.count()):`